# What is the Java equivalent for the following in curl?

Tags: java, curl

```
curl https://view-api.box.com/1/documents \
-H "Authorization: Token YOUR_API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"url": "https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/4qhegqxubg8ox0uj5ys8.pdf"}' \
-X POST
```

How do you accomodate the url?

This is what I tried so far.

```
final String url = "https://view-api.box.com/1/documents";

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        post.setHeader("Authorization", "Token: TOKEN_ID");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        final List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", "https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/4qhegqxubg8ox0uj5ys8.pdf"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        final HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use an HTTP client?

Comment: mkyong has posted [some examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah. I am having issues using the HTTP client. I added what I tried so far.

Comment: ... and yet none of the examples in the link shared above really solves this particular problem (sending a raw body in a post).

Answer (score 0):

You have everything ok except the entity, what you're sending in `curl` is not the content of an html form but a json object.

First take off this part (don't send your data as if it were application/x-www-form-urlencoded):

```
// comment out / delete  this from your code:
final List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", "https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/4qhegqxubg8ox0uj5ys8.pdf"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
```

And then add the body in this way:

```
BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
InputStream body = new ByteArrayInputStream(
    "{\"url\": \"https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/4qhegqxubg8ox0uj5ys8.pdf\"}".getBytes());
entity.setContent(body);
post.setEntity(entity);
```

I'm assuming that your JSON string only have chars between 0x20 and 0x7F, but if you use other characters (like Ñ) then you need to transform your data to a bytearray using the encoding UTF-8 (the standard encoding used in JSON data) in this way:

```
BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
String myData = "{\"url\": \"https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/4qhegqxubg8ox0uj5ys8.pdf\"}";
ByteArrayOutputStream rawBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(rawBytes,
        Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
writer.append(myData);
InputStream body = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawBytes.toByteArray());
entity.setContent(body);
post.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following - although I can't remember if the StringEntity is available under HTTPClient

```
    final String url = "https://view-api.box.com/1/documents";

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    post.setHeader("Authorization", "Token: TOKEN_ID");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    post.setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"url\": \"https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/4qhegqxubg8ox0uj5ys8.pdf\"}"));

    final HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

}
```